# Cannot use Moq library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, moq

I am using `VS13 Community Edition` I want to use `Moq` in my project. To do so, I went to `Nuget Package Manager` and searched `Moq` but no relevant result was there. But I found library named 'Moq: an enjoyable mocking library' and I installed that in my project. But I cannot use it in my project.

**Screens**

How I installed library

[image]

Error

[image]

Comment: There is no `Moq` reference found in your project. Did the nuget installation succeed?

Comment: Yes, I already used EF from that

Comment: No, I mean your Moq package installation is likely failed

Comment: Make sure you have the Package Manager Console view open, and that the testing project is selected (I'm assuming you're trying to unit test). Then, type in `Update-Package -reinstall Moq`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that although you downloaded the NuGet package, something did not succeed as the DLL wasn't added to your references.

Two things you should do:

1. Make sure it downloaded succesfully
2. Manually add a reference to Moq.dll.

I suggest looking at the `Package Manager Console` provided with VS for more detail.

Comment: Nuget came with visual studi itself and i am not able to add dll manually. Its not allowing me to browse dll, may be virus effect?

Comment: I dont think so. Go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> NuGet Package Console. That should open a console window. Try looking if there are any error there.

Comment: It's also under View -> Other Windows -> Package Manager Console.

Comment: Done :) You saved me.. I was so frustrated that I wanted to uninstall vs.. Thank alottt.

Answer (score 0):

Check you have add the Moq library as a referance in your unit test application.

I think You removed the Moq reference from your project.

From your 2nd image I get their isn't any reference for using **Moq**.

Please check if you add the reference like below picture.

[image]

If you are not able to see it means. Just follow the bellow.

Please note you have to check in you Installed application menu in below link not in online menu as you did in your 1 image.

In your Project please uninstall the **Moq** library first. like in below picture.

[image]

Then you have to install the **Moq** again from the online menu like below.

[image]

After installing the Moq library now you can able to use the Moq Reference.